# How much of this is needed to read ticks from the BIOS (8086)?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-16, dos

I have the following function (C with assembly) that reads BIOS ticks:

```
static clock_t clock(void);
#pragma aux clock = \
"pushf" \
"push ds" \
"cli" \
"mov ax, 0x0040" \
"mov ds, ax" \
"mov bx, 0x006C" \
"mov ax, [bx]" \
"sti" \
"pop ds" \
"popf" \
parm [ ax ] \
modify [ ax bx ];
```

This works, but how much of it is necessary? Can someone help me code golf this a bit? I'm working with 8086 (tiny memory model), and I'm not sure if I need to `pushf` and `popf` or `cli` and `sti` before reading the value. I'd also appreciate if it's possible to reduce the number operations. I know nothing about far pointers and fudged this together (first time).

Comment: Obviously you don't need to go through a register for addressing, you can just do `mov ax, [0x6c]`. If your compiler supports the `modify` clause for a segment register you don't need save `ds` (or `es`).  Since you only have a single memory read disabling interrupts doesn't do anything useful so you can get rid of the whole `pushf`/`cli`/`sti`/`popf` business. Also since this is just a memory read, you don't need inline asm for it, just do `return *(volatile clock_t*)MAKE_FAR(0x40, 0x6c);` (use whatever way your compiler provides to create a far pointer).

Comment: I gather from the syntax this is  Watcom/Openwatcom C/C++

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, this is OpenWatcom. @Jester Thank you for the list of suggestions. If I just `mov ax, [0x6c]`, I get `108`. However, your second suggestion about returning the value is just fine if I can ditch `pushf`/`cli`/`sti`/`popf`. I have one question though, if you are happy to remove clearing/setting interrupt, why mark the pointer as `volatile`?

Comment: Because otherwise if you have repeated reads of the clock (as you likely will) the compiler may decide to optimize out the extra accesses thinking the value did not change in memory. It may also reorder the clock reading with respect to code you probably want to time.

Comment: @Jester Presumably disabling interrupts with `cli` was supposed to guard against tearing when two memory accesses would happen to read the entire 32-bit timer tick value. In 8086-compatible Real/Virtual 86 Mode there may be an alternative though, which is to use `lds ax, [6Ch]` (or `les`, and using whichever GPR destination). This is possibly not atomic, but probably good enough to avoid hardware interrupts (IRQs) interfering. But that won't work in Protected Mode code, or bimodal code that should be able to work in Protected Mode as well (like most of my debugger).

Comment: @ecm: In code that requires 386 protected mode, you can simply do a 4-byte load into a 4-byte integer register.  As a single instruction, that's atomic wrt. interrupts.  (Unlike m68k for example, an x86 instruction fully happens before an interrupt or not at all.)  If you mean 286 protected mode, then yeah, les/lds would be a problem.  If you had x87, `fild dword` / `fistp dword` can do a 4-byte load as a single instruction, but IDK if x87 accesses are async wrt. CPU interrupts, and it would probably be way slower than `cli` / `sti` on a real 286 + HW FPU, let alone with soft-FP emulation.

Comment: [Interrupting an assembly instruction while it is operating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55180452) re: Intel documentation backing up the fact that a single instruction is atomic wrt. interrupts.  (And thus atomic wrt. other threads on a uniprocessor machine, as well as wrt. any interrupt handlers.  `lock` is only useful for interacting with devices in that case; threads on a uniprocess is the [use case for `cmpxchg` without `lock`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837731/is-x86-cmpxchg-atomic-if-so-why-does-it-need-lock)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to read a word from address `0000:046c` to get the low 16 bits of the tick counter.  An easy way to do this is to use a far volatile pointer:

```
#include <i86.h>

#define ticks (*(volatile unsigned short __far *)MK_FP(0x0000, 0x046c))
```

Other equivalent addresses like `0040:006c` can be used, too.

You can then access the ticks counter as such:

```
int now;

now = ticks;
```

Note that this will only give you the low 2 bytes.  If you want all bytes, you'll have to disable interrupts to do an atomic read of the whole counter (or loop until convergence).

You can also use the predefined functions `clock` or `_bios_timeofday` as indicated in [the manual](https://open-watcom.github.io/open-watcom-v2-wikidocs/clib.html#BIOS_Functions) for this purpose.